# Aes Encryption in C# Decrypt using other IV

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

They say you can decrypt the data by using the same secret key but another Initialization Vector,
How to achieve that one?
Example:
My IV for encryption is as follows byte[] bytes = {12,12,5,12,32,62,91,16,89,92,17,72,45,52,13,42};
but for my Decryption is random IV that is 16bytes in length.

Comment: Who are they, and where do they say it?

Comment: With CBC, incorrect IV only corrupts the first block, since the next block effectively only requires the previous encrypted block. With a relatively small block size and a file format that is relatively tolerant to corruption in the early bytes, it would seem incorrect IV still "works"

Comment: So it is not achievable to decrypt using differet IV?
I just saw it online.

Comment: It would appear to work on a tolerant format such as JPEG for example. The result will still be a legible image, but the first block is actually lost.

Comment: I suspect _they_ either misunderstood or conveyed it wrongly to you. You use different IVs for each messages, yes, so that the same unencrypted message sent twice will not look the same encrypted. The IV can be passed as plain text as part of the message - it doesn't matter that an attacker can see it - it's just used to randomize the message encrypted with the key. But the IV does need to be the same on both side for a particular message.

Comment: As has already been stated, an incorrect IV for CBC on decrypt will result in an incorrect first 16 bytes. After those 1st 16 bytes the decryption will be **correct**. So if you have an encrypted file of 1000016 bytes then the last 1000000 bytes will be correctly decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `SymmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor()` with the same IV that was used for encrypting.

Quoting from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/decrypting-data):

> The SymmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor method from the Aes instance is passed the IV value and the same key that was used for encryption.

Code sample, also from docs page:

```
Aes aes = Aes.Create();
CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(
    fileStream,
    aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
    CryptoStreamMode.Read
);
```